# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Button Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a memory game. This is what I have so far. How do I solve this problem? If there is any tips that would help in making a memory game using Tkinter, that would be much appreciated!

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import random

difficulty = 16
rowsize= 4
columnsize = 4
numcount = 0
lastnum = 0
gotitcorrect = False

root = Tk()
root.title("MEMORY GAME!!")
root.configure(bg='gray')

def GameStart():
    menuFrame.pack_forget()
    gameFrame.pack()

def Timer(tim):
    time.sleep(tim)

def GetRandomNumber():
    lst1 = [i for i in range(1,9)]
    lst2 = [i for i in range(1,9)]
    random.shuffle(lst1),random.shuffle(lst2)
    numlst = lst1+lst2
    return numlst

def WrongOrRight(card, number):
    if numcount == 0:
        lastnum = number
        numcount+=1
        card.configure(text=str(number))
    elif numcount == 1:
        if number == lastnum:
            gotitcorrect = True
            card.configure(text=str(number))
        else:
            gotitcorrect = False
            card.configure(text='')
        numcount -= 1

menuFrame = Frame(root, bg='gray')
menu = [Label(menuFrame,text='MEMORY GAME', bg = 'gray'), Button(menuFrame,command = GameStart,text = 'Start', bg='gray')]
for i in menu:
    i.pack()
menuFrame.pack()

numlst = GetRandomNumber()
print(numlst)
gameFrame = Frame(root, bg='gray')
cards = [[Button(gameFrame) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
index = 1
card_dict = {}
for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        print(index)
        cards[x][y].grid(row = y, column = x, padx=20,pady=20)
        cards[x][y].configure(text = str(numlst[index-1]))
        cards[x][y].configure(command = lambda: WrongOrRight(cards[x][y],numlst[cards[x][y]]))
        card_dict[cards[x][y]] = numlst[index-1]
        index+=1
Timer(5)
for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        cards[x][y].configure(text = '')


root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(rowsize,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(columnsize,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This is my error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "memorygame.py", line 62, in <lambda>
    cards[x][y].configure(command = lambda: WrongOrRight(cards[x][y],numlst[cards[x][y]])) TypeError: list indices
must be integers or slices, not Button
```

Comment: `cards` contains buttons. What do you want `numlst[cards[x][y]]` to do?

Comment: `numlst[cards[x][y]]` gives the number that `cards[x][y]` is assigned to. Does that help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You're getting the error because `cards[x][y]` returns a button, and then you essentially have `numlst[Button(gameFrame)]`; but lists can't be indexed with buttons.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You're right! Thank you for helping me. Will that help solve my error or is there something else that is incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure what result you're wanting, so I can't suggest how to fix that error. On top of that though, `command = lambda: WrongOrRight(cards[x][y],numlst[cards[x][y]])` will give you problems. It will always use the last value of `x` and `y`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463498/late-binding-python-closures) for how to fix that.

Comment: That's true. The website you linked did give me the insight to call a function in a for loop. But what is the difference between that and not having a func at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code with a number of changes. It fixes the `TypeError` and gets rid of the `card_dict`. Its not really needed anyway because that number assigned to each card can easily be stored by adding an attribute to the `Button` widget representing the card. Doing this also means you only have to pass the card to the `WrongOrRight()` function.

All important changes have been indicated with `# ALL CAPS COMMENTS`. I also made cosmetic changes to the code so it followed the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in an effort to make it more readable and I *strongly* suggest that you read and follow the guidelines in the future yourself.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import random

difficulty = 16
rowsize= 4
columnsize = 4
numcount = 0
lastnum = 0
gotitcorrect = False

root = Tk()
root.title("MEMORY GAME!!")
root.configure(bg='gray')

def GameStart():
    menuFrame.pack_forget()
    gameFrame.pack()

def Timer(tim):
    time.sleep(tim)

def GetRandomNumber():
    lst1 = [i for i in range(1,9)]
    lst2 = [i for i in range(1,9)]
    random.shuffle(lst1), random.shuffle(lst2)
    numlst = lst1+lst2
    return numlst

def WrongOrRight(card): # REMOVED NO LONGER NEEDED SECOND ARGUMENT.
    global lastnum, numcount, gotitcorrect  # ADDED

    number = card.number  # ADDED
    if numcount == 0:
        lastnum = number
        numcount += 1
        card.configure(text=str(number))
    elif numcount == 1:
        if number == lastnum:
            gotitcorrect = True
            card.configure(text=str(number))
        else:
            gotitcorrect = False
            card.configure(text='')
        numcount -= 1

menuFrame = Frame(root, bg='gray')
menu = [Label(menuFrame, text='MEMORY GAME', bg='gray'),
        Button(menuFrame, command=GameStart, text='Start', bg='gray')]
for i in menu:
    i.pack()
menuFrame.pack()

numlst = GetRandomNumber()
print(numlst)
gameFrame = Frame(root, bg='gray')
cards = [[Button(gameFrame) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
index = 1
#card_dict = {}  # NOT NEEDED
for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        print(index)
        cards[x][y].grid(row=y, column=x, padx=20, pady=20)
        cards[x][y].configure(text=str(numlst[index-1]))
        # ADDED DEFAULT ARGUMENTS TO LAMBDA FUNCTION TO MAKE IT WORK PROPERLY
        cards[x][y].configure(command=lambda x=x, y=y: WrongOrRight(cards[x][y]))
        cards[x][y].number = numlst[index-1]  # ADD ATTRIBUTE TO BUTTON WIDGET
#        card_dict[cards[x][y]] = numlst[index-1]  # NOT NEEDED
        index += 1

#Timer(5)  # DISABLED FOR TESTING
for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        cards[x][y].configure(text='')

root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(rowsize,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(columnsize,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the revised code! This really helped to understand the problem.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please up-vote it. Thanks!

Comment: I would love to, but sadly, I don't have enough reputation to like posts. Sorry!

Comment: That issue should be fixed now… `;¬)`

Answer (score 1):

Cards is a list of buttons:

```
cards = [[Button(gameFrame) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
```

Later in the code we have:

```
cards[x][y].configure(command = lambda: WrongOrRight(cards[x][y],numlst[cards[x][y]]))
```

the code above tries to access `numlst` while it uses a Button as index.