# Function not changing with for-loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Tkinter GUI in which, if a button is clicked, its text gets changed to a corresponding item in a list `matches`.

The list `matches` and list `buttons` are not known yet. My code looks something like this:

```
#Defining the buttons
buttons = []
for i in range(len(matches)):
    buttons.append(Button(my_frame, text = " ", 
        font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 1, width = 1,
        command = lambda: change(i)))


def change(index):
    if buttons[index]['text'] == matches[i]:
        buttons[index]['text'] = " "
    else:
        buttons[index]['text'] = matches[i]
```

Whichever button I press, the text changes only for the last button. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of [lambda's late bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463498/what-does-late-binding-closures-mean)

To avoid that, use `functools.partial` instead of `command = lambda: change(i)))`

```py
import functools 

buttons = []
for i in range(len(matches)):
    buttons.append(
        Button(
            my_frame,
            text=" ",
            font=("Helvetica", 20),
            height=1,
            width=1,
            command=functools.partial(change, i)
        )
    )
```

Another simpler option is to replace

`command = lambda: change(i)))`

with

`command = lambda i=i: change(i)))`