# On clicking the numbers to input it onto the entry widget, it always adds 10 rather than the number supposed to

Tags: python, tkinter

```
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(3):
        button = tk.Button(text=str(num+1),master=window,padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda:button_click(num+1))
        button.grid(row=i,column=j)
        num+=1


def button_click(Number):
    ent_number.insert(tk.END,Number)
```

Whenever I click any button, which shows the appropriate numbers i.e 1,2,3,etc. it always inserts 10 to the entry widget.

Comment: You use `num+1` in your code, but you don't define it. Where does it come from, and is `num` maybe equal to 9?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71716380/function-not-changing-with-for-loop-python

Comment: @SriramSrinivasan Yes that does. If it isn't a bother, why does lambda num=num: button_click(num) solve this? Is it because lambda has a property where it will change the value as we go in the for loop? Thanks

Comment: I will add the explanation for that in an answer.

Comment: @AfifMohammedVarikkodan Was the explanation in the answer clear to you? If you have any doubts, please feel free to ask.

Comment: @SriramSrinivasan yes it did. Thank you for your explanation, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily solve your problem by making `num` a default parameter:

```
lambda num=num: button_click(num)
```

### Why does this work?

A *pre-defined* variable in a function could either be a parameter or a global variable. The first preference goes to the function parameter.

For example, if you execute the below code, it will print out 10, not 6.

```
def func(num):
    print(num)
    
num = 6
func(10)
```

In your code, when you use `lambda:button_click(num+1)`, `num` is considered a global variable and the value of `num` is always 10 irrespective of which button triggered the event.

However, when `num` is passed as a parameter, the parametric value doesn't change with iterations of the loop. When the function is executed, the parametric value of `num` is considered, which depends on the source button.