# Tkinter is not being stopped by sleep. Why?

Tags: python, tkinter

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm making a python project that automatically opens my meet links for class! The whole thing went well, but now i want a loading screen. Imagine this:

New window pops up
Label appears: "Welcome to google meet!"
i slowly config the label using time.sleep() to decrease visibility.
then the label gets replaced by my app GUI!
Sounded great in my head! Until i built it. The Time.sleep wasnt working, and it automatically skips to the next stage: GUI! and if i remove the gui part, it just stays blank.

My code:

```
#----------------SETUP-----------------------
from datetime import datetime

import pickle
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

import datetime
import time
# all my imports
m = Tk()

W = Label(m, text="Welcome to google meet!", fg="#000000")
time.sleep(0.2)
W.pack()
time.sleep(1.2)
W.config(fg="#434343")

time.sleep(0.2)
W.config(fg="#8c8c8c")

time.sleep(0.2)
W.config(fg="#d2d2d2")

time.sleep(0.2)
W.config(fg="#eeeeee")

time.sleep(0.2)
W.config(fg="#ffffff")
W.destroy()


def Load():
    w=Button(m, text="Open meet",bg="#F0F0F0", highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
    m.title("Meet for Aparicio by ")
    top = Tk()
    top.title("Club Form")
    copyrightt = Label(m, text="All rights reserved. Copyright by  . Do not distribute as your own, but link to the google docs.")
    L2 = Label(top, text="If this is your first time using this app, please fill out the form. If not, you can just ignore it.")
    L2.pack()
    copyrightt.pack()
    ba = Button(top, text="Submit!") # there was a ,command=submit) but since i deleted the command, i just remvoed this for now, since i only need the GUI.
    L3 = Label(top, text="Academic club link")
    L3.pack()
    E2 = Entry(top, bd =5)
    E2.pack()



    L5 = Label(top, text="Pastoral link")
    L5.pack()
    E4 = Entry(top, bd =5)
    E4.pack()




    L7 = Label(top, text="Interest link")
    L7.pack()
    E6 = Entry(top, bd =5)
    E6.pack()
    ba.pack()
    m.geometry("700x250")
    label = Label(m,text="Press the button below to open the link!")
    img = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/PKSNFL/Documents/Untitled.png") # make sure to add "/" not "/"

    label.pack()
    w.config(image=img)
    w.pack()
    wekday = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

    if wekday == 3:
        l2 = Label(m, text="DISCLAIMER: IF YOU RUN THIS TWICE FROM 1:00 PM TO 2:00 PM, MESSAGE    ON HOW TO FIX IT.")
        l3 = Label(m, text="If you don't, the app will give you the wrong link for the rest of its life until you fix it :D")
        l2.pack()
        l3.pack()
Load()
#--------------------------------------------

#
m.mainloop()
```

I have cut out the code for my meet, and it has no relation to my tkinter code, except for the submit button.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  This is missing imports and some definitions to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The only thing `time.sleep()` does in a Tkinter application is lock up the GUI, preventing any screen updates from happening.  Tkinter provides an `.after()` method for scheduling function calls to occur in the future, which is the appropriate approach here.

Comment: Sorry, @MarkTolonen. Will fix!

Comment: @jasonharper Oh, Now i get it! Thanks!

Comment: There are many very similar questions on this site, all about how sleep seems to freeze tkinter. Have you done any research before asking this question?

Comment: @BryanOakley... Yes. Not really on this site, but other public sites like tutorialspoint or geeksforgeeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, `time.sleep` locks the GUI and prevents any screen updates from taking place. If you want to schedule GUI function calls, you must use:

```
<widget>.after(<delay-in-milliseconds>, <function>)
```

I have used a constant sleep duration of 0.2 seconds to achieve the transition. You can modify the durations according to your preference.

```
time = int(sum(sleep_times[:i+1]) * 1000)
```

calculates the cumulated time from the start of the transition.

The reason for using `lambda clr = fg_clrs[i]: W.config(fg = clr)` instead of `lambda : W.config(fg = fg_clrs[i])` is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798866/on-clicking-the-numbers-to-input-it-onto-the-entry-widget-it-always-adds-10-rat/71799742#71799742) answer.

---

### Working Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
fg_clrs = ("#000000", "#434343", "#8c8c8c", "#d2d2d2", "#eeeeee", "#ffffff")
sleep_times = (0.2,) * 6
label = Label(root, text="Welcome to google meet!", fg="#000000")
label.pack()

for i in range(len(sleep_times)):
    time = int(sum(sleep_times[:i+1]) * 1000) 
    root.after(time, lambda clr = fg_clrs[i]: label.config(fg = clr))

root.mainloop()
```