# How to handle variables of multiple check buttons inside a menu in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to make a multi-selection dropdown list in Tkinter so browsing online I came to the solution of using `add_checkbuttons` into a menu. The solution it's working, at least graphically, but now I want the GUI to actually do something when a check is marked. I tried with a simple function that print the value as a command for each check button but it's only being called once.

Here's my code so far:

```py
root = tk.Tk()

groceries = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot']

def print_groceries(bucket,item):
    print(bucket[item].get())

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
viewMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
bucket={}
for item in groceries:
    bucket[item] = tk.BooleanVar(False)
    viewMenu.add_checkbutton(label = item, variable = bucket[item], command=print_groceries(bucket,item))
menubar.add_cascade(menu = viewMenu, label = "Buy")
root.config(menu = menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned the return value of `print_groceries` to the `command` parameter. Therefore, when your code is executed, `print_groceries` is executed thrice at the time of *defining* the checkbuttons. As all the checkbuttons are unchecked initially, you see that `False` is printed thrice.

---

### Solution:

The `command` parameter takes a function, not the value returned by a function (unless the return value is itself a function).

To create a simple function, you can use `lambda` as shown below:

```
lambda <parameter-1>,<parameter-2>,... : <task-to-perform>
```

Also, you must use `lambda bucket=bucket, item=item: print_groceries(bucket,item)` and not `lambda : print_groceries(bucket,item)`. You can find the reason for the same in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798866/on-clicking-the-numbers-to-input-it-onto-the-entry-widget-it-always-adds-10-rat/71799742#71799742) answer.

---

### Working Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

groceries = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot']

def print_groceries(bucket,item):
    print(bucket[item].get())

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
viewMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
bucket={}
for item in groceries:
    bucket[item] = tk.BooleanVar(False)
    func = lambda bucket=bucket, item=item: print_groceries(bucket,item)
    viewMenu.add_checkbutton(label = item, variable = bucket[item], command = func)
menubar.add_cascade(menu = viewMenu, label = "Buy")
root.config(menu = menubar)

root.mainloop()
```