# Why async function binds name incorrectly from the outer scope?

Tags: python, asynchronous, namespaces, closures, python-asyncio

Here is an async function generator by iterating a `for` loop. I expected this closure to respect the names from the outer scope.

```py
import asyncio

coroutines = []
for param in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9):

    async def coro():
        print(param ** 2)
        # await some_other_function()
    
    coroutines.append(coro)


# The below code is not async, I made a poor mistake.
# Michael Szczesny's answer fixes this.
for coro in coroutines:
    asyncio.run(coro())
```

While I was expecting the results to be `1, 9, 25, 49, 81` after running, here is the actual output:

```
81
81
81
81
81
```

Unexpectedly here, the name `param` has taken the same value each time.

Can you explain why this happens and how I can achieve the task of creating lots of async functions in a `for` loop with names binding correctly?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [late binding closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463498/what-does-late-binding-closures-mean)

Comment: To fix it rewrite your coroutine to `async def coro(param=param)`

Comment: This isn't specific to coroutines. This is just the default python behavior associated with all function definitions (and closures).

Comment: This code does not run asynchronously or uses *coro* as a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The included code does not run asynchronously or uses *coro* as a closure. Functions are evaluated at runtime in `python`. An asynchronous solution would look like this

```py
import asyncio

def create_task(param):
    async def coro():
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # make async execution noticeable
        print(param ** 2)
    return coro                # return closure capturing param

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[create_task(param)() for param in (1,3,5,7,9)])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output after 1 second

```
1
9
25
49
81
```

Comment: Please check the update on question. `coro` function shouldn't take `param` as parameter by my program's design. I also added asynchronous code into `coro` function.

Comment: Your program's design is specifically why it's not working as you expect.

Comment: I don't understand your update, but I edited the answer to use an async closure with the desired binding of *param*.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny The closure update solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only once the `coro` function is run, will it evaluate the line:

```py
print(param ** 2)
```

At that time, it will check the value of `param` and evaluate it. So what is the value of `param` then?

Looking at the code, we can see that the `param` value is set during iteration:

```py
for param in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9):
    ...

# For loop is over, param is now equal to 9
# since it was the last value it iterated on
```

Then only **afterwards** is the `coro` function run:

```py
for coro in coroutines:
    asyncio.run(coro())  # 'param' is still set to 9, meaning that the output will always be 81
```

You could instead add a parameter to the `coro` function:

```py
async def coro(coro_param):
    print(coro_param ** 2)
```

... and pass the parameter to the function **when it is called**:

```
for param in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9):
    asyncio.run(coro(param))
```

Comment: I don't understand. That isn't a class.